# Listing package showing newline after the last line of code

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I haven't been able to suppress this newline only with configuration. In the [`listings` documentation](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) it is said that the `showlines` option if set to `false` won't let the newline appears, but that is not working for me. How to make it work?

[image]

I can make it work by inserting latex comments inside the listing, but that is kind of annoying, specially if there is a option in the package to do it.

**Update:**

Minimum working example as requested:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}  

% "listing" definitions ========================================
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{pink}{rgb}{0.8, 0.55, 0.6}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  commentstyle=\color{mygray},       % comment style
  deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
  keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,       % keyword style
  language=Python,                 % the language of the code
  morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
  numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  numberstyle=\color{black}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showlines=false,
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  stepnumber=1,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
  tabsize=2,                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{lstlisting}
{
    "name": "create menu"
}
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: question updated!

Comment: Please try and reduce the problem. Many of the packages you have are not related to your problem. Not only does it make it easier for people to help you, it sometimes also lets you discover any errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\begin{lstlisting}
{
    "name": "create menu"
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

`\end{lstlisting}` should start in the *first* column!

Comment: Is there any option to let listings ignore this line? My auto indention indents the `\end{listing}`, to move it to the start of the line is very annoying.